# Wpf Type initialization failed, type initializer threw an exception

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

currently I am updating, MainViewModel property from sub view using this code.

On MainViewWindowViewModel:

```
public static MainViewModel Instance { get; } = new MainViewModel();

private bool toggleEventDataParsingButton;
public bool ToggleEventDataParsingButton
{
    get => toggleEventDataParsingButton;
    set
    {
        toggleEventDataParsingButton = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

On sub view it is simple just set up property:

```
MainViewModel.Instance.ToggleEventDataParsingButton = true;
```

But weird thing is on MainWindow.xaml, there is a button:

```
<Button Margin="0 0 0 5" Height="35" Content="3. Event Data Parsing" Command="{Binding SetDataParsingViewModel}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=(local:MainViewModel.Instance).ToggleEventDataParsingButton}" />
```

And it bindet to man window property that is changes, so if something happens on sub view this property is changed and button is enabled.

Thing is it compiles and works, but on designer I am getting

> Type 'MainViewModel' initialization failed, The type initializer threw an exception.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding ToggleEventDataParsingButton, Source={x:Static local:MainViewModel.Instance}}"
```